Check if a channel still contains a task of a certain type
I am using the .NET Channels to add jobs to it and work on them in a consumer, producer fashion.
However, sometimes it could be handy to check weather a job of a certain kind is still in the "pipeline"?
Is it possible to check weather an object that fulfils certain conditions is still inside the channel?
Lets say this is the type of objects inside the channel:
public class MyJob
{
     public string Id {get; set; }
     public string Type {get; set; }
     ...
}

And then my task queue:
Channel<MyJob> _queue;

I would now like to check (not modify!!!) the _queue if jobs of a certain kind are inside the pipeline.
Something like this:
var kindExists = _queue.Reader.Where(j => j.Type == "MASTER").ToList();
if(kindExists)  ...

I saw that there is the possibility to "peek" a job with the _queue.Reader.PeekAsync, but I am not sure if this is the correct thing to do.

Peeking only really works here if you organize your channels by task type in the first place - if the channel associated with a given type returns true on TryPeek => at least 1 job of said type still queued

Mhh... not really what I need. My tasks are not sorted in any way and cant be... :(
